# PHP Subtract Date with hours and minutes

Tags: php, time, subtraction

Hi I've search the internet about this topics and seems can't give me the right ouput?
What could I be doing doing wrong? I want to output the remaining days from an expiration period with hours and minutes.

Here's what I've done,

```
$date_expire = '2014-09-12 23:59:59';  
$date = new DateTime($date_expire);
$now =  new DateTime();
echo $date->diff($now)->format("%d days, %H hours and %i minutes");
```

I am from the philippines and the current date and time I wrote this is August 13, 2014 5:26pm
the ouput gives me 29 days, 12 hours and 30 minutes. Which is think is wrong? Can you help me? thanks!

Comment: The server may have an other timezone. Set it in your `php.ini` or with `date_defualt_timezone_set`

Comment: Instead of `%d` use `%a` which will return total numbers of day difference.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the `%a` is the way to go. Here combined with a simple check on whether some subscription has expired or not.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

// August 13, 2014 5:26pm
$date_now    = '2014-08-13 17:26:00';
$date_expire = '2014-09-12 23:59:59';

$now     = new DateTime($date_now);
$expires = new DateTime($date_expire);

$diff = $expires->diff($now)->format("%a days, %h hours and %i minutes");

if ($now < $expires) {
    echo "Your subscription will expire in $diff", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "Your subscription expired $diff ago", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Your subscription will expire in 30 days, 6 hours and 33 minutes
```

Running it today, with `$now = new DateTime();` this output is given:

```
Your subscription expired 168 days, 2 hours and 56 minutes ago
```

Answer (score -1):

your source code is working fine and it does what you expect.

yes, on that date was missed 29 days 12 hours and 30 minutes and a few months.

the problem is that you don't print out the months (:

here, there is your script with the months included:

```
// this is your start date
$date_expire = "2014-09-12 23:59:59";
// build a DateTime instance from it
$date = new DateTime($date_expire);
// another instance for the date of NOW
$now =  new DateTime();
// print the difference with %m (months) included
echo $date->diff($now)->format("%m months, %d days, %H hours and %i minutes");
```